# How do I retrieve the element of an array as an object property

Tags: javascript, properties, key

My question is why is this function not passing the test that it `should return the element at the index of the array at the key of the passed in object`.

The problem is:

Given an object, a key, and a numerical index, "getElementOfArrayProperty" returns the value of the element at the given index of the array located within the given object at the given key.

Notes:
* If the array is empty, it should return undefined.

- If the given index is out of range of the array located at the given key, it should return undefined.
- If the property at the given key is not an array, it should return undefined.
- If there is no property at the key, it should return undefined.

When I pass the sample object: `var obj = { key: ['Jamil', 'Albrey'] };` it returns `"jamil"`.

My Code:

```
     function getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, key, index) {

    if (!obj["key"]) return undefined
      return obj["key"][index]
    }

    getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, "key", 0)  // returns "jamil"
```

Yet it still fails the test

Comment: Your example works because the value you chose for the argument `key` is the string `"key"`.

Comment: I know, I'm doing challenges (learning) and that is what it gives me.  How would I do this if 'key' wasn't in quotes.  Shouldn't this still pass that requirement though? i'm getting "jamil" when i run it.

Answer (score 1):

I think Nol is right. The problem is that there is a little confusion with `key` as a property / parameter and "key" as a string literal. Let's see if this clear the things up:

```js
var obj = { foo: ['Jamil', 'Albrey'] };

function getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, key, index) {
    if (!obj[key]) return undefined;
    return obj[key][index];
}
    
alert( getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, "foo", 0) );
```

**EDIT**: And if you are wondering why `"foo"` is between quotes, that's because it is not a variable, it is a string literal with the name of the object's property. If you want to pass a variable as parameter, first you need to create it, like:

```
var bar = obj["foo"]; // or  
var bar = obj.foo;
```

And then you can use it in the function invocation:

```
alert( getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, bar, 0) );
```

But in this case, you don't need to pass the `obj` variable, because `bar` already refers to one property of the `obj` object:

```js
var obj = { foo: ['Jamil', 'Albrey'] };
var bar = obj.foo;

function getElementOfArrayProperty(key, index) {
  if (!key) return undefined;
  return key[index];
}

alert(getElementOfArrayProperty(bar, 0));
```

Comment: I understand that. I'm not quite sure why it returned key is undefined when I didn't put it in quotes in my function.   btw how do I do code snippets in comments?

Comment: Comments, as far as I know, don't support snippets. (if you mean to highlight the code, you need to wrap it between  back-ticks) And, in my snippet, the variable `key` has not quotes... or do you mean the quotes on `"foo"` inside the `getElementOfArrayProperty` invocation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a typo, but in your code example, you are passing in the string "key" to obj like `obj["key"]` instead of using the parameter `key` from your method definition. Using `obj[key]` might improve your results.

Here's what I meant:

```js
   var obj = {
     key: ['Jamil', 'Albrey']
   };

   function getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, key, index) {

     if (!obj[key]) {
       return undefined;
      }
     return obj[key][index];
   }

   function getArrayByKey(obj, key) {
       return obj[key];
   }

   alert(getElementOfArrayProperty(obj, "key", 0) + "\n" + getArrayByKey(obj, "key"));
```

You'll see that this doesn't return undefined if you run it, instead it returns Jamil just like your example with the hard-coded `"key"`.

If I look for just `obj[key]` I still end up getting the whole array object, so I can't seem to reproduce your issue.

Comment: When I return obj[key] (without quotes), it said key is undefined, even if I use a 'for (var key in obj) ' @Nol